# How do I ssh-add a protected key to ssh-agent for my Jenkins CI instances?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, jenkins

I manage a Jenkins CI server running on Ubuntu 14.04 with a few requirements:

- Jobs make use of public/private key authentication for security, so an identity must have been added to ssh-agent prior to executing them
- Our private key files must be passphrase protected
- We cannot store that passphrase in an insecure location (like a script source-code or Jenkins configuration files)

Ideally, I want to ssh-add and enter passphrase on the order of *once per reboot.* But I can't figure out how to get Jenkins CI to run its jobs in a way that takes advantage of this authentication.

Is it possible to get Jenkins to take advantage of identities added to an ssh-agent in advance?
Is there an alternative strategy I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 2):

Run `ssh-agent` with a static socket path, under the same UID as Jenkins uses:

```
sudo -u jenkins ssh-agent -a /tmp/ssh-agent.jenkins
```

Make sure the `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable points to that path. You will want to set it 1) manually before ssh-add'ing your keys, and 2) in the Jenkins startup script (e.g. `/etc/init.d/jenkins` or equivalent):

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/tmp/ssh-agent.jenkins"

sudo -E -u jenkins ssh-add ...
```